# 2 masses pushed in same direction on a frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics

2 blocks of mass $m_1$ and $m_2$ are placed side by side on a frictionless surface. $m_1$ block is pushed with a force $F_1$ and block is pulled with a force $F_2$.(leading to both forces being eventually in the same direction but on different bodies). [image: pictorial representation of the problem.]Find acceleration and normal reaction between both blocks​

Comment: Is it required that both blocks remain in contact with one another?  I assume the blocks are on a horizontal surface?

Comment: Both blocks on frictionless horizontal surface. Not necessary that blocks remain in contact. They may or may not be in contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a force balance separately on m1 and m2 and determine when F2 is sufficiently large so that the blocks cannot have the same acceleration and thus remain in contact.  For this case there is no normal force and the blocks have a different acceleration. For F2 less than this value the blocks have the same acceleration and you can find the acceleration and normal force by doing force balances on m1, m2, and (m1 + m2).

Comment: Could you plz give more explanation?

Comment: Assume no normal force.  Do force balance on m1 and then on m2; evaluate a1 and a2 and find F2 relative to F1 for which a2 =a1.  then, for any F2 greater than that value you have the answer.  Then, for any F2 less than that value the blocks move together (a = a1 = a2) and you find a and normal force by force balances on m1, m2, then (m1 +m2).